# Excel bug: Formula moves when referencing other worksheets

Tags: excel

Many times when I'm creating formulas (and it seems to happen more often when they are more complex formulas) the location of the formula moves to the sheet I'm referencing.  For simplicity, if I'm in A1 on Sheet1 and I type "=" then select Sheet2 and click on M13 such that the formula then reads "=Sheet2!M13, when I hit return, that formula will show up in cell A1 of Sheet2 instead of Sheet1.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing in those instances that creates this issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have never once had that happen and it sounds very very frustrating. Just the same, I think this would be better asked on superuser.com (or a microsoft site since this does sound like a bug). Stackoverflow.com is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create the behavior that you are seeing.

If you happen to hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key during Sheet selection, then **both** Sheets 1 & 2 may become `Selected` *(as a group)*.

If this is the case, then it is possible for the formula to get deposited in cell **A1** in both Sheets !

Comment: Yes, and in the top bar (where you see your workbook name) it will have this "[group]" after the workbook name.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the version?  I can't get control-sheet to select anything when I am in the middle of a formula...  Mine is the latest office 365 version.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah  **I was not clear.**  I meant selecting **before** any formula entry.

Comment: Brilliant  - Didn't knew this before however totally makes sense !